# Oracle performance questions, inner selects in joins, temporary WITH tables indexes

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I would like to consult three aspects of performance (Oracle 11g).

1./ If I define temporary table by keyword "WITH" like

```
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT [columns from both tables...] 
    FROM table_with_inexes 
    JOIN other_table ...
)
SELECT ... 
FROM tbl
JOIN xxx ON tbl.column = xxx.column
```

is subsequent select on that temporary table able to use indexes, that was defined on table_with_inexes and other_table?

2./ Is it possible to add indexes to temporary table created by "WITH" in that above-like single SQL command?

3./ When I have construct such as this:

```
...
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT indexedColumn, otherColumns
     FROM table
     JOIN other_table
     GROUP BY ...
) C
ON (outerTable.indexedColumn = C.indexedColumn)
```

in which cases could Oracle use indexes on indexedColumn? I assume, that the select in LEFT JOIN is only "projection" that does not maintain indexes, so the join's ON clausule evaluation is evaluated without using indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WITH` clause (or subquery factoring as it's known as) is just a means of creating aliases for subqueries. It's most useful when you have multiple copies of the same subquery in your query, in which case Oracle may or may not choose to create a temporary table for it behind the scenes (aka "materialize" it). You should read up on this - [here's a good link](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php).

To answer your questions:

1) If the indexes are available to be used (no functions on the columns involved, selecting a small percentage of the data etc, etc) then they'll be used, just like in any other query.

2) You can't add indexes to the subquery. Not even to the temporary table that Oracle might create behind the scenes; you have no control over that.

3) I suggest you read up about when indexes might or might not be used. Try http://www.orafaq.com/node/1403 or http://www.orafaq.com/tuningguide/not%20using%20index.html, or perform your own google search.

Comment: Thanks Boneist! I am aware I need to read deeply about Oracle, I just needed to quickly orient in this particular features first. I am definitely going to study those links. I would just appreciate any elaboration of that 3rd point. Is that the same scenario as 1)? If that inner select only picks column from some "relation" of two joined tables, without applying any functions, then - is Oracle able to use index on that column? (i.e. when it works with some joined assembly of two tables, does the "assembly" hold the index from original tables?). Optional to answer, will read the links :)

Comment: @LalitKumarB: thanks! I was planning to study something like this as a next step :).

Comment: To complete the picture: The official name defined in the SQL standard for the `WITH` construct is "common table expression" - "subquery factoring" is the term that Oracle uses (maybe because it was available in Oracle before this was part of the SQL standard - similar to window functions aka "analytical functions")

Comment: @RomanNovotný> Oracle's optimizer will use indexes if a) it's possible to do so and b) it makes sense to do so. The main purpose of an index is to make it easier/quicker to look up data, similar to how an index works in a book (eg. if you're going to look through all or most of the pages of a book, it doesn't make sense to look though the index first).

Answer (score 0):

`WITH` clause might be either inlined or materialized. It's up to Oracle to decide which approach is better. In your case most probably both queries will have the same execution plan(will be inlined)

PS: even if the table is materialized, indexes can not be added, Oracle can not do that. On the other hand in most cases it is not even necessary, the table can be materialized as a hash table(not heap table) or full table scan is used on it.